# How to hide the index page of a directory from the browser URL display

Tags: php, .htaccess

I do `header('Location: '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to reload the same page (solution found to avoid `confirm form resubmission` popup when a user refreshes the page).

Then the URL displayed in the browser is `http://www.example.com/index.php`, which is not nice, displaying `http://www.example.com/` would be preferred.

**What should I do on PHP side or .htaccess side to have `<address>/` displayed in the URL bar instead of `<address>/index.php` ?**

Comment: `header("Location: /");exit;`? have you tried this? Did it fail?

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not a particularly good variable to use, as it can be manipulated by the client. `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` (or similar) would be better

Comment: @Martin if `http://www.example.com/blah/index.php`, won't `header("Location: /");` redirect to `http://www.example.com/`, which is not correct?

Comment: I understand that when you want to load a page that is a directory index you don't want the page name shown in the browser? Therefore `example.com` == `example.com/` == `example.com/index.php` == the page you want to load?

Comment: When reloading the page `http://www.example.com/blah/` from PHP (I edited question to explain why), I would like the URL bar to display `http://www.example.com/blah/` instead of `http://www.example.com/blah/index.php`.

Comment: yes, so then does the suggestion I posted (edited to show the correct folder) such as `header("Location: /blah/"); exit;` not work? try it?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` / `.htaccess` is irrelevant here - as stated, the redirect occurs after a form submission is processed to avoid the "Do you want to resubmit" popup warning when a user refreshes the page.

Comment: @Martin I would like to do it without hardcoding it, i.e. if I move the folder, it should follow without hardcoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, stripping the directory index from `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` might be sufficient for your needs. For example:

```
$url = str_ireplace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'index.php','');
header('Location: '.$url);
exit;
```

Note that using variables like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly in your script without validation can open your site up to vulnerabilities, since these variables can contain user manipulated content.

Comment: Thanks. Last thing: is it possible to do this *if and only* if mod_rewrite is enabled? I'm designing a tool that people will install. Some people might not have mod_rewrite enabled, then doing this would make it fail...

Comment: What does this have to do with mod_rewrite? This doesn't require mod_rewrite, if that is what you are thinking? For a URL like `http://www.example.com/blah/` to route successfully on Apache requires mod_dir (`DirectoryIndex`) - which is enabled by default (I have never seen this disabled).

Comment: If user A doesn't have mod_rewrite on, won't `/` fail, and require `/index.php` instead?

Comment: Yes, mod_dir issues an internal subrequest to the directory index (`index.php`, or `index.html`, whichever is defined and the server finds first).

Comment: The `SCRIPT_NAME` variable does not contain the query string, so it's already _removed_. The `SCRIPT_NAME` variable is literally the root-relative file system path of the script being processed.